# Make a div go full opacity when another is hovered

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with this: http://jsfiddle.net/1904837j/

As you can see, when I hover over an image, the text that goes visible is the one under the next image.

What I want is have the text show up under the image being hovered over.

Here is the code:

***HTML:***

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="cats">
        <div class="adminmenu"><a href="ipban.php"><img src="<?php echo $host ?>/img/admin/ipban.png"></a><div class="undername">Test</div></div>
        <div class="adminmenu"><a href="ban.php"><img src="<?php echo $host ?>/img/admin/ban.png"></a><div class="undername">Test</div></div>
        <div class="adminmenu"><a href="smileys.php"><img src="<?php echo $host ?>/img/admin/smiley.png"></a><div class="undername">Test</div></div>
        <div class="adminmenu"><a href="setup.php"><img src="<?php echo $host ?>/img/admin/gear.png"></a><div class="undername">Test</div></div>
        <div class="adminmenu"><a href="forums.php"><img src="<?php echo $host ?>/img/admin/forums.png"></a><div class="undername">Test</div></div>
        <div class="adminmenu"><a href="adminlogoff.php"><img src="<?php echo $host ?>/img/admin/quit.png"></a><div class="undername">Test</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS:***

```
.header .cats{
    margin-top:15px;
    text-align:center;
}

.header img{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.adminmenu{
    display:inline-block;
}

.adminmenu:hover + .adminmenu .undername{
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.adminmenu .undername{
    font-size: 10px;
    color:white;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're targeting `.adminmenu` child, so use:

```
.adminmenu:hover .undername{
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1904837j/1/)

Explanation: with `.adminmenu:hover + .adminmenu .undername` you are targeting the **next in level** `.adminmenu` elements child element that has `.undername` class, and that's why in your fiddle it *works* for the next element.